# Qml fullscreen окно

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gui, qml

Необходимо раскрыть главное окно во весь экран, подскажите как это сделать?

Нагуглил что можно выводить так:

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true 
    visibility: Window.FullScreen
}
```

В cpp использую QQmlApplicationEngine, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если ещё не нашли, то почитайте параметры QApplication, на официальном сайте все описано.

Comment: [Вот](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html) - константы и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как ответов в принципе хороших не было то решения данной задачи дам я сам. Вдруг кому то поможет. Для полного экрана при использовании данного сочетания qml и qt необходимо дописать следующую строчку

```
visibility: "FullScreen"
```

в блоке ApplicationWindow.